# Cast to compiletime unknown generic type

Tags: java, generics, casting

So, I got a problem with casting to an unknown (at runtime) generic method argument.

```
ValueDescription<?> valueDesc = /* get the value description */;
Object value = /* get the value */;
valueDesc.gotAValue(valueDesc.getType().cast(value));
```

The abstract class ValueDescription looks like this:

```
public abstract class ValueDescription<T> {

    public abstract Class<T> getType();

    public void gotAValue(final T value) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Eclipse allways gives the following error:
The method gotAValue(capture#1-of ?) in the type ValueDescription is not applicable for the arguments (capture#2-of ?)

Is it even possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code into a generic method:

```
<T> void doStuff(ValueDescription<T> valueDesc) {
  Object value = /* get the value */;
  valueDesc.gotAValue(valueDesc.getType().cast(value));
}
```

This allows the compiler to know that the `getType()` and `gotAValue` "`?`s" are the same type, even when you don't know the `T` directly:

```
ValueDescription<?> valueDesc = /* get the value description */;
doStuff(valueDesc);  // Fine, even though you've only got ?.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not supposed to know the actual generic type of `ValueDescription`, then you should let the class do it for you.

```
public abstract class ValueDescription<T> {

    public abstract Class<T> getType();

    public void gotAValue(final Object value) {
        final T castedValue = getType().cast(value);
        // Continue
    }
}
```

If you do this, you may need to throw an appropriate exception if the `Object` type `value` cannot be casted to the actual type.

If it is possible to determine the type of `valueDesc`, then use [Andy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50906359/2970960).

### Edit

Actually, if you do not know the type of `ValueDescription`, then it is likely that this class does not need to have generic at all. `getType()` can simply return a `Class<?>` and subclass just needs to override it to return the correct `Class` object.